# NoReverseMatch: Unable to set named group in URL in Django

Tags: python, regex, django

I am getting this error for going to the url : `http://127.0.0.1:9000/mypolls/anyerror`

```
NoReverseMatch at /mypolls/anyerror
Reverse for 'mypolls' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['mypolls/(?P<error_message>.*)$']
```

My urls.py contains:

```
from django.conf.urls import url  
from . import views
urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$',views.home,name='home'),
    url(r'^polls/$',views.list,name='list'),
    url(r'^polls/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$',views.detail,name='detail'),
    url(r'^polls/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/vote$',views.vote,name='vote'),
    url(r'^mypolls/(?P<error_message>.*)$',views.mypolls,name='mypolls'),
    url(r'^create/$',views.create,name='create'),
    url(r'^polls/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit$',views.edit,name='edit'),
    url(r'^polls/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/delete$',views.delete,name='delete'),
]
```

My views.py contains:

```
def mypolls(request,error_message=None):
    polls=Poll.objects.filter(author=request.user)
    return render(request,'polls/list.html',{'polls':polls,'error_message':error_message})
```

What is wrong here?

My list.html contains:

```
{% extends 'polls/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% if error_message %}
<p>{{error_message}}</p>
{% endif %}
{% for poll in polls %}
<li><a href='{% url "detail" pk=poll.pk %}'>{{ poll.question }}</a>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: @alecxe Added the complete contents

Comment: Please show the `polls/list.html` template.

Comment: Try adding the end of string match character `$` to the url pattern for `mypolls`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Adding $ still gives same error.

Comment: The list template looks ok. The problem might be in `polls/base.html`.

Comment: Something is not accurate here. The error message says your regex is .+, your urlconf shows .*

Comment: @LawrenceDeanVanderpool That's because I had updated the url when Moses Koledoye asked me to try doing so. I forgot to update the error message.

Comment: glad you figured it out either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in base.html. I did not give the keyword argument in url for mypolls in base.html. Now I have set the url as:

```
{% url "mypolls" error_message="" %}
```

and it is working fine.
Thanks @Alasdair and everyone.